# How do you make HTTP requests with Raku?

Tags: raku

How do you make HTTP requests with Raku? I'm looking for the equivalent of this Python code:

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "python"}
url = "http://example.com/"
payload = {"hello": "world"}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may want to try out the recent [HTTP::Tiny](https://modules.raku.org/dist/HTTP::Tiny) module.

```
use HTTP::Tiny;
my $response = HTTP::Tiny.new.get( 'https://example.com/' );
say $response<content>.decode
```

Comment: Thanks, that seem better than what I was doing. That page also led me to `HTTP::UserAgent`. I added another related question here, because the responses from them are producing unexpected results when I convert the responses from JSON. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014105/extracting-json-from-a-raku-http-client-request-perl-6

Answer (score 11):

After searching around a bit, I found an answer in the [Cro docs](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-client).

```
use Cro::HTTP::Client;

my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.get('https://api.github.com/');
my $body = await $resp.body;

# `$body` is a hash
say $body;
```

There's more information on headers and `POST` requests in the link.

Answer (score 5):

I want to contribute a little more. There is a fantastic module named [WWW](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/WWW).
It's very convenient to make 'gets' that receive json because it can be parsed automagically.

In their example:

```
use WWW;
my $response = jget('https://httpbin.org/get?foo=42&bar=x');
```

You can examine the objects using the basic functionalities of arrays and hashes, for example to extract the values of my response you can use:

```
$response<object_you_want_of_json><other_nested_object>[1]<the_last_level>
```

Here the number [1] are a nested list inside a hash, and the properties are the same. Welcome to the raku community !!!

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, but when I do `zef install WWW` it asks for my Github username and password in the terminal, which makes me a little nervous. Should it be doing that when I install packages with zef?

Comment: I too am having issues with ```zef install WWW``` and have raised an [issue][1] 


  [1]: https://github.com/raku-community-modules/WWW/issues/19

Comment: Looks okay now: `Installing: WWW:ver<1.005006>:auth<github:raku-community-modules>`