# Extracting JSON from a Raku HTTP client request

Tags: raku

I'm having trouble understanding what is wrong with this Raku code.

I want to fetch JSON from a website, and print out a field from each item in an array within the JSON (in this case the titles of latest topics from any Discourse forum).

This is code that I expected to work, but it failed:

```
use HTTP::UserAgent;
use JSON::Tiny;

my $client = HTTP::UserAgent.new;
$client.timeout = 10;

my $url = 'https://meta.discourse.org/latest.json';
my $resp = $client.get($url);

my %data = from-json($resp.content);

# I think the problem starts here.
my @topics = %data<topic_list><topics>;
say @topics.WHAT;  #=> (Array)


for @topics -> $topic {
    say $topic<fancy_title>;
}
```

The error message is from the `say $topic<fancy_title>` line:

```
Type Array does not support associative indexing.
  in block <unit> at http-clients/http.raku line 18
```

I would have expected that `$topic` should be written as `%topic`, because it's an array of hashes, but this doesn't work:

```
for @topics -> %topic {
    say %topic<fancy_title>;
}
```

The error message for that is:

```
Type check failed in binding to parameter '%topic'; expected Associative but got Array ([{:archetype("regula...)
  in block <unit> at http-clients/http.raku line 17
```

If you inspect the data, it should be a hash, not an array. I tried `@array` but I know that isn't correct, so I changed `%topic` to `$topic`.

I finally got it to work by adding `.list` to the line that defines `@topics` but I don't understand why that fixes it, because `@topics` is an `(Array)` whether that is added or not.

This is the working code:

```
use HTTP::UserAgent;
use JSON::Tiny;

my $client = HTTP::UserAgent.new;
$client.timeout = 10;

my $url = 'https://meta.discourse.org/latest.json';
my $resp = $client.get($url);

my %data = from-json($resp.content);

# Adding `.list` here makes it work, but the type doesn't change.
# Why is `.list` needed?
my @topics = %data<topic_list><topics>.list;
say @topics.WHAT;  #=> (Array)

# Why is it `$topic` instead of `%topic`?
for @topics -> $topic {
    say $topic<fancy_title>;
}
```

Does anyone know why it's failing and the correct way to perform this task?

Comment: Re: _Why is it `$topic` instead of `%topic`?_ , I tried `%topic` in the same position and got the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happened is that you've created an array of an array when you say

```
my @topics = %data<topic_list><topics>;
```

This isn't unique to these modules, but general across Raku with array assignments.

Let's take a simpler hash to see what's going on:

```
my %x = y => [1,2,3];

my $b = %x<y>;
my @b = %x<y>;

say $b;  # [1 2 3]
say @b;  # [[1 2 3]]
```

The catch is that the array assignment (which is used when the variable has the `@` sigil) interprets `%x<y>` *as a single item* as it's in a scalar container, which it then happily puts in `@b[0]`.  While you can't control the module itself, you can see the difference in my example if you say `my %x is Map = …` as `Map` do not place items in scalar containers, but `Hash` objects do.  There are two ways to tell Raku to treat the single item as its contents, rather than a single container.

- **Bind the array**
  Instead of using `@b = %x<y>`, you use `@b := %x<y>`.  Binding to `@`-sigiled variables decontainerizes automatically.
- **Use a zen operator**
  When you want to avoid the possibility of a list/hash value being treated as one, you can use a zen slice to remove any container if it happens to be there.  This can be done *either* at assignment (`@b = %x<y>[]`) *or* at the `for` loop (`for @b[] -> $b`).  Note that `<>`, `[]`, and `{}` are effectively synonymous, regardless the actual type — most people just use the one that matches the previous.

So in your code, you could just do:

```
...
my %data = from-json($resp.content);

my @topics := %data<topic_list><topics>;   # (option 1) binding
my @topics  = %data<topic_list><topics><>; # (option 2) zen slice

for @topics -> $topic {
    say $topic<fancy_title>;
}
```

Or in your loop, as option 3:

```
for @topics<> -> $topic {
    say $topic<fancy_title>;
}
```

The reason that the `.list` fixes things — as you can probably surmise after the rest of the answer — is that it returns a fresh list that isn't in a container.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did do something like `%data<topic_list><topics>[]` at one point due to a typo (must have not pressed `0` hard enough) and it worked, but I thought that it was an accidental quirk of the language that probably wasn't the right way to do things. :) I'll experiment with both of the methods you mentioned.

Comment: `[]` is empty, yet returns everything, hence the name *zen slice* (that and it kind of looks like two hands in meditation to me).  The issue you've encountered, btw, is why I personally try to have my modules return `Map` and `List` objects whenever possible instead of `Hash` or `Array`, since the latter ones containerize their values.

Comment: "There are two ways to tell Raku to treat the single item as its contents, rather than a single container." Aren't there loads of them? Aiui the essential issue is the ambiguity between the dual plural / singular nature of any plural thing. Is an `Array` a single thing (an array) or a list of things (the contents of the array)? If a value is in a `Scalar` then Raku presumes you want to treat whatever is in the `Scalar` as a single thing. But if your code (not just your mind!) treats it as a plural thing, then you get the contents. Thus `|`, `.list`, `flat`, et al, will all work, right?

Comment: I haven't learned `Map` and `List` yet, but I'll research them. I've only looked through raku.guide but just found this page and will read it https://docs.raku.org/language/list

Comment: @raiph: I could be wrong, but my understanding of `slip`, `.list`, and `flat` is that they are fairly transformative — you won't get back the original list per se (although it's entirely possible that `.list` does return the original).  It's true, though, that it's a distinction without a difference in 95+% of cases.

Comment: @raiph decont is necessary if you're doing directly to the `for` loop in some cases.  I know I've run into it once or twice where I *had* to use `for foo.bar(…)<> { … }`.  But honestly, using some of other techniques can make code more explicit, particularly the `.list`

Comment: Hi @user0721090601 I wanted more clarity on when a zen slice is valuable. The official doc is one source but is often too ambiguous for me. So I popped onto SO, searched for "`[raku]` zen slice", read your answer and these comments. The quality of your exposition lit the world up. It's so much easier to see clearly with such a powerful light.  Thank you!